# How to record the time for testing

Tags: testing, go

I wrote two functions and now I would love to find out, which of them is faster. How can I find it out, which one is faster?

How can I find out by testing, which one is faster? Do go provide a timer for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even better, Go provides a built in benchmark and testing functionality!

Create a file named **something_test.go** (must have the *_test* part).

```
func BenchmarkFunc1(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = Func1()
    }
}

func BenchmarkFunc2(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = Func2()
    }
}
```

Then simply run: `go test -bench=. -benchmem`

It will print how long each function took and memory usage / allocations.

Ref:

- http://golang.org/pkg/testing/
- http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/30/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go

Answer (score 3):

You could write a benchmark for each function.

See for instance "[How to write benchmarks in Go](http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/30/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go)"

```
// from source_test.go
func BenchmarkFunction1(b *testing.B) {
        // run the Function1 function b.N times
        for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
                Function1(10)
        }
}
```

Repeat for `Function2` and check the results with `go test -bench=.`